# Multiple Threads Accessing Same Nested Dictionary

Tags: python, multithreading, dictionary

(warning incoming novice). I am about to run a multi threaded python script that will go through 100s of thousands of files, and will update a dictionary. More specifically the threads will be appending to a list that is stored in a nested dictionary.

For example `Dict['X1']['X1PROPERTIES']` where `'X1PROPERTIES'` is a list.

Now depending on which file a thread is currently reading, there may be cases where multiple threads are appending to the same X#'s `PROPERTIES`. After reading about atomic properties and locks, what I was wondering is if I will require the use of locks. To my understanding if it is simply appending to a list in place I will not need to use locks, but I am a bit unclear on which cases locks are necessary.

Any Insight will be much appreciated.

To add a little bit more context here, the actual processing being done on the data extracted from each file is very minimal and the result is either an append in place to a list inside a global dictionary or nothing. It is really just the sheer volume of directories and files I need to navigate through. The time spent reading in files is brutal. Are there more effective solutions I can use to speed up the IO component? I am wondering if I may be misusing threading in this context.

Comment: Use the locks, save yourself many headaches.

Comment: If you're a novice, a good idea is to start with a single-threaded version of this. From there you can potentially split up your input and run multiple instances of your single-threaded script. But starting out with the most convoluted solution possible is probably not worth the hassle. Start with simple and working and move up in complexity.

Comment: Using a `Lock` guarantees concurrent access will be safe and they're easy to create and use since they support `with` context management. Might as well use them rather than trying to determine whether one is necessary every occasion. At best what you're doing is premature optimization which is often a waste of **your** time.

Comment: Python has a thread-safe `Queue` as an alternative to locking, you could have an architecture where the changes are written to a queue and a special thread is listening to it and handling the writes. This will delay writes but speed up processing. It you need the data to be always up to date it might not be an option.